# Do the "ls" on the fly

Tags: 18.04

I am sure this is something that might get downvotes but I want to know how to achieve the following?

[image]

Comment: The screenshot is demonstrating the usage of [Friendly Interactive SHell](https://fishshell.com/) ( or FISH  for short) . You can install if via "sudo apt install fish" and run it with just "fish".

Comment: The screenshot is a 404 for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The screenshot is demonstrating the usage of [Friendly Interactive SHell](https://fishshell.com/) ( or FISH for short) . You can install it via

```
sudo apt install fish
```

and run it with just

```
fish
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean this advanced auto-completion in command line, you can install zsh (z-shell) and use it instead of bash. To do this enter following command:

```
sudo apt install zsh
```

Then try to install oh-my-zsh  from its official website to customize your z-shell with it. You can also install plugins and themes.

Then you should just change your shell from bash to zsh via :

```
chsh your_username -s /usr/bin/zsh
```

Comment: Although zsh has nice auto-completion features but the screenshot in the OP's question is fish. And traversing the directories in that way is the signature of fish.

Comment: I think I can do this traversing with zsh

Comment: Pragmatically yes , but visually not exactly.